# Adding Theme.Holo in android manifest returns resource not found error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I've been trying to add the Holo Dark theme to my android application. For this I have added the following to the application tag of the android manifest xml file.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo"
```

This produces an error which says Resource not found that matches the given name. Any ideas on how to get past this ?

PS: I am just beginning android development.

**Edit 1**

The only step I've taken to add the Holo theme for android application is the addition of the above mentioned line of code. DO I have to import any files to the styles folder in the project ?

Comment: What android version of android are you running? Holo is available as from honeycomb.

Comment: I am running for APIs greater than 14 that is IceCreamSandwich or later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a system resource. `@style` uses only resource that are defined by you. `@android:style` uses system resources:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't get the changes the first time I saw your reply.